# Simple Memory Game: found nil error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, swift3

I've built a simple memory game where the user is suppose to tap on a card until all the cards are paired. However, my issue is that when the user taps on two cards, the game crashes after 2 seconds "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping".

I've double checked all my images and made sure they are hooked up correctly but i still get the error. my code below:

```
@IBOutlet weak var frontImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var backImageView: UIImageView!

var card: Card?{
    didSet {
        guard let card = card else {return}
        frontImageView.image = card.image
    }
}

fileprivate(set) var shown: Bool = false

//Mark:- Card function properties

func showCard(_ show: Bool, animated: Bool){
    frontImageView.isHidden = false
    backImageView.isHidden = false //This is where i get the error.
    shown = show

    if animated {
        if show{
            UIView.transition(from: backImageView, to: frontImageView, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromBottom, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
            })
        } else {
            UIView.transition(from: frontImageView, to: backImageView, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromBottom, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
            })
        }
    } else {
        if show{
            bringSubview(toFront: frontImageView)
            backImageView.isHidden = true
        } else {
            bringSubview(toFront: backImageView)
            frontImageView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: What line is crashing?

Comment: What @DuncanC said. Set a breakpoint, figure out which line is crashing, and based on your code, I'd bet you can solve this without our help.

Answer (score 0):

At least one of your outlets is nil. There is many reasons e.g: you forgot to connect your outlets to your xib/storyboard file, you call `showCard` before `viewDidLoad`, you create view purely from code, not instantiating from storyboard/xib file.

Like @dylanthelion suggest you should debug code and look at your code stack. You should also paste more code here.

Keep enabled exception breakpoints in your code:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvnqBjzEKuk